# How do I include a yet to be defined variable inside a string? PHP

Tags: php, variables

For sake of performing less database queries and for clarity of code, I'd like include a yet to be defined variable inside a string. Later in the page, the variable will be declared and the string printed and evaluated. How do i do this?

```
$str="This $variable is delicious";

$array=array("Apple","Pineapple","Strawberry");

foreach($array as $variable)
{
  print "$str";
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) (or [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) if you don't want to echo it):

```
$str = 'This %s is delicious';

foreach ($array as $variable) {
    printf($str, $variable);
}
```

Comment: Or sprintf() if you don't actually want to echo it. +1

Comment: @Mchl Thanks; incorporated into the answer

Comment: or vsprintf() if you want to add arguments dynamically (for the i8n you most likely would) :-P

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace`.

For example:

```
$str = "This is [VARIABLE] is delicious";
$array = array("Apple", "Pineapple", "Strawberry");

foreach($array as $variable)
{
    print str_replace('[VARIABLE]', $variable, $str);
}
```

Comment: @stereofrog: It's possible to swap order of variables in (v|s)printf(). See example #3 here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
$array=array("Apple","Pineapple","Strawberry");

foreach($array as $variable) {
    print "This $variable is delicious";
}
```

Comment: That would work. But this isn't the actual code I'm working with. I just used it for the purpose of the example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need php's sprintf function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

or it can also be done using str_replace

http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing wrong way.
Learn to use templates and you will never need such odd things.
Just divide your code into 2 parts:

- getting all required information
- displaying a regular page or an error page

you will find that all your code become extremely neat and reusable

Comment: The OP might be using this for i8n

Answer (score -2):

```
$str='This $variable is delicious'; // so no variable interpolation is performed

$array=array("Apple","Pineapple","Strawberry");

foreach($array as $variable)
{
  // Warning! This is a very bad idea!
  // Using eval or system might create vulnerabilities!
  eval('$str="' . $str . '";');
  print $str;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea indeed. Not worth downvoting though, because it's noted on the answer it's a bad idea.