# How to echo from MySQL when MySQL has a variable

Tags: php

I currently have a row in a mysql table that has a variable in it, $item1. I wanted to know if there is a way to have it act as a variable. It would be easier for the project I'm working on if these variables could be stored in the mysql table and still remain dynamic.

When trying to echo this row, $item1 comes out as $item1, instead of acting as a variable.

So the mysql table looks like so

[image: image of the table.]

And the code looks like this.

```
$item1 = "Test";
echo "$row[1];"
```

As stated instead of getting "Hello Test"
I am getting
"Hello $item1"
Is there a way around this?

Comment: try this for echo variable 

`echo $row['1'];`

Comment: saving variables is not a good idea. you need to save it's value to db. And then you can easily get the data. again you can assign this data to any variable name which you feel comfortable.

Comment: Your question is really not as clear as it looks. Maybe [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) can help.

Comment: I added an image to make my question a bit more clear. While I would stray away from putting variables into a database, due to a rather specific feature that is being coded I am told to attempt this beforehand.

Comment: Please don't use `eval()` and dont uset varialbe outside of PHP code. Here is better way using placeholders like `%s as replace it through `sprintf()` or str_replace()`.

Comment: sprintf() works well for this and is far less risky, thank you. I'll keep the question open to see if there are more methods before closing.

Comment: Definitely don't use `eval`. I meant to show there are more than one way to achieve this. Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624092/how-do-i-include-a-yet-to-be-defined-variable-inside-a-string-php/3624131

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function of php. But it has nothing to do with `mysqli`

```
$item1 = "Test";
$itemFormDatabase = "$item1";
echo eval($itemFormDatabase)
```

Result

> Test

But a note of caution: eval just executes everything as php code. If an attacker can modify the value given to it, he can do anything